# Blacklisting a module only for specific kernel versions?

Tags: drivers, grub2, kernel, modprobe, blacklist

When I boot a 4.4.x kernel, I want to make sure that the buggy staging driver `r8723au` is blacklisted, in favor of the much-improved mainline [`rtl8xxxu`](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.wireless.general/143417).

However, when I boot an older 4.2.x kernel, I'll still need to use the old `r8723au` driver.

Is there any way to blacklist a module *only* for a specific kernel version? (**UPDATE:** I want to blacklist the *old* module, `r8723au`, from the *new* kernel, to prevent it from taking over from the new driver.)

Ideas I had:

- `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8723au.conf` -- it's not possible to specify blacklist only for one kernel version, as far as I can tell
- `/etc/default/grub` -- no way to specify `modprobe.blacklist=r8723au` for the kernel command line for some versions and not others

The quick-and-dirty solution I've got is to manually edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and add the relevant blacklist parameter to specific kernel versions… but of course this will be overwritten automatically the next time I run `update-grub` (perhaps when installing an updated Xenial/16.04 kernel).

Answer (score 2):

The module rtl8xxxu doesn't exist in kernel version 4.2.0-xx, as far as I know, so booting into a 4.2.0-xx kernel should be fine.

I am not aware that the two drivers cover the same usb.ids, however, you can keep r8723au from loading in 4.4.0-xx by renaming the modules. For instance:

```
sudo mv /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723au/r8723au.ko  /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723au/r8723au.bak

sudo mv /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723au/r8723au.ko  /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723au/r8723au.bak
```

You will need to repeat the process when an updated kernel version, -23 perhaps, is installed by Update Manager.

Comment: Right, but I'm not trying to blacklist the *new* module; I'm trying to blacklist the *old* module. *Both* exist in the new kernel, and the problem is that when I boot 4.4.x then the `r8723au` driver grabs the device, when I want `rtl8xxxu` to take it.

Comment: Yes, and by renaming the *old* module, as I suggest, it will be unable to load in 4.4.0-xx as you wish.

Comment: Just for my education, what is your device ID from: `lsusb`? Thanks.

Comment: It's `0bda:1724` … why do you ask? AFAICT, the `r8723au` driver only probes [three specific USB IDs](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/blob/master/os_dep/usb_intf.c#L59-L61).

Comment: I asked because I was unaware that the device 0bda:1724 wa covered by two separate drivers. I have confirmed from *modinfo* that is indeed so. I appreciate the heads up. I suggest that you proceed with the rename I proposed.

Comment: Sure, and thanks for your suggestion! This is one of those odd cases where the vector (Realtek) provided a working-but-big-and-ugly driver for Linux. It went into staging, but then a volunteer wrote a much cleaner (and more stable) driver. I do think it's rare for there to be two open source drivers for the same hardware. Are you one of the Ubuntu wireless maintainers, by any chance?

Comment: I am not; I'm just a somewhat skilled forum nerd.